# Using reCAPTCHA from a different machine results in "ERROR: Invalid domain for site key"

Tags: recaptcha

reCAPTCHA works well on localhost, but when I try accessing it from a different machine, it gives me this error:

> ERROR: Invalid domain for site key

Yet I am using the same keys generated from [the reCAPTCHA site](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run reCAPTCHA on localhost you should use a secure token like described here: [Google secure token documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token)

This solved my own localhost problem. Previously I had an error message "Invalid domain for site key". This may be because nobody says that a localhost has to be named 'localhost' or have the standard IP address used for localhosts. Anyway, using the secure token solved this completely.

For secure token generation I'm using [slushie's PHP implementation](https://github.com/slushie/recaptcha-secure-token)

The PHP part:

```php
<?PHP
    use ReCaptchaSecureToken\ReCaptchaToken as ReCaptchaToken;
    require_once("libs/ReCaptchaToken.php");

    //Generate reCAPTCHA token
    $config = [ 'site_key'    => 'place-your-site-key-here',
                'site_secret' => 'place-your-secret-key-here'
              ];
    $recaptcha_token = new ReCaptchaToken($config);
    $recaptcha_session_id = uniqid('recaptcha');
    $recaptcha_secure_token = $recaptcha_token->secureToken($recaptcha_session_id);
?>
```

The HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  ...
    <script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
    ...
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="place-your-site-key-here" data-stoken="<?PHP echo $recaptcha_secure_token; ?>"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I try accessing it from a different machine

If you try to access it from outside, Google (all of the Internet) sees your external computer IP address (IP address of your computer on the WWW) unrelated to `127.162.0.0`. So that's why it throws the error.

I recommend you to set reCAPTCHA into a real web page and register at Google.

Comment: that could be one solution to it. what i did and solved the problem was to register both ip for server( running localhost) and client(the one i used to access the application from).

Comment: Igor Savinkin what do you do inorder for the application to be accessed from any machine without adding IP Address of each client accessing the application every now and then

Comment: @bademba, consider [this post](https://webscraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
and register your domain. It will work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.